# setting up play2-statsd plugin

Tags: playframework-2.0, statsd

I am using play framework v2.1.2 & am trying to use play-plugin for statsd - (https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/statsd).  I was able to run sbt reload without any issues.  However, when I try to import the following into my Java class, I get an error (in eclipse) - "the import play.modules cannot be resolved".

```
import play.modules.statsd.Statsd;
```

I have tried reload and play eclipse but that has not resolved the issue.  I also tried another play2-statsd plugin but the sbt import did not work at all for me.  Any insight on troubleshooting/fixing this will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse refresh (F5) after "play reload" & "play eclipse" worked for me.